# Value Error: could not broadcast input array from shape (857,3) into shape (857)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I've been trying to plot a database that I parsed from a text file into a numpy array. The array has 857 rows.

This error keeps popping up, I dont understand what it means.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

def parseFile(file):
    F = open(file)
    n = len(F.readlines())  #no. of lines in file
    numpyMat = numpy.zeros((n,3)) # create numpy matrix
    classLabelVector = []
    F = open(file)          # from the beginning again
    i = 0
    for line in F.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        listFromLine = line.split()
        numpyMat[i,:] = listFromLine[0:3]   # 3 is the no. of variables/columns
        classLabelVector.append(int(listFromLine[-1]))
    i+=1
    return numpyMat, classLabelVector

dataMatrix = parseFile('kiwibubbles_tran.txt')

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(dataMatrix[:1], dataMatrix[:2])   # Error

plt.show()
```

Error: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (857,3) into shape (857)

Comment: What's the shape of `dataMatrix`?

Comment: It's a 857 X 3 matrix, if that's what you mean

Comment: maybe you want it to say: `ax.scatter(dataMatrix[:,1], dataMatrix[:,2])`

Comment: You return a tuple from the parse file function but you don't unpack it when calling the function, i.e. your `dataMatrix` is not the matrix itself but a tuple that also contains the label vector.

Comment: @waterboy5281 That gives me a Type Error, saying that the tuple indices must be integers or slices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `dataMatrix` is a tuple, so you have two options:

**Take the results of the fuction in two different variables**:

```
numpyMat, classLabels = parseFile('kiwibubbles_tran.txt')
fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(numpyMat[:,1], numpyMat[:,2])

plt.show()
```

**Plot only the numpyMat from the tuple**:

```
dataMatrix = parseFile('kiwibubbles_tran.txt')
fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(dataMatrix[0][:,1], dataMatrix[0][:,2])

plt.show()
```

Comment: That helped. Thanks a lot! :D